# How to specify Conv2d input shape based on a simple numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

i have a small problem with my network i have data with a shape like:

```
z = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]).astype(float)
z = np.expand_dims(z, axis=0)
print(type(z))
print(z.dtype)
print(z.shape)
```

output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
float64
(1, 14)
```

and i want add to my network conv layer, without it everything work fine.

```
nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Dense(32, input_dim=14, activation='relu'))
nn.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

#nn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

nn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

nn.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
           optimizer='rmsprop',
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but when i add conv layer i got an error:

```
nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Dense(32, input_dim=14, activation='relu'))
nn.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

nn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

nn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

nn.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
           optimizer='rmsprop',
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/main.py", line 95, in 
    main()
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/main.py", line 75, in main
    bestmodel = nnmodel.best_model()
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/NNmodel.py", line 25, in best_model
    nn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 181, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 311, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

i need to add just one conv2d layer for school project, can u help me ?